# How can I add text into ckeditor textarea in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm using [ckeditor-7.2](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) version. How can I set the values to my ckeditor text area from out side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to set some value at the beginning -

Get the id of the form. https://www.drupal.org/project/get_form_id

Get the id of the field you want to alter.

Make a small custom module, with hook_form_alter() and set #default_value to that :

```
function YOURCUSTOMMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( YOUR_FORM_ID == $form_id) {  
    $form['YOUR_FORM_ID']['YOUR_FIELD_ID']['#default_value'] = 'some default text'
  }
}
```

For adding some text after taht that, use jQuery.

```
$('#input-field-id').val('some text');
```